# Непонятная ошибка 'Empty SQL Statement'

Tags: delphi

Может кто-нибудь подсказать в чем ошибка?

```
with IBQuery1 do
begin
SQL.Clear;
SQL.Add(запрос);
if not IBTransaction4.Active
then IBTransaction4.StartTransaction;
try
ExecSQL;
IBTransaction4.Commit;
except
IBTransaction4.Rollback;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IBQuery1.Close;
IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
IBQuery1.Sql.Add('');
IBQuery1.Open;
```

Не записывается в IBQuery1.Sql ваш запрос вот и матерится
сами посмотрите (Memo1 только бросьте на форму):

```
SQL.Add(запрос);
Memo1.Text:=SQL.Text;
```

Comment: я тоже сначала так подумал, однако, данные в БД заносятся, а ошибка вылетает при подтверждении транзакции

Comment: Не рекомендуется стартовать или завершать транзакции обращением к свойству IBTransaction.Active

убери условие if not IBTransaction4.Active then,а IBTransaction4.StartTransaction оставь

Comment: @NMD записал данные в мемо перед подтверждением транзакии - запрос на месте

Comment: вы уже говорили это

Comment: @NMD убрал условие, однако, проблема не решилась: данные в БД записываются, но ошибка вылетает.

Comment: @NMD вообще такой ошибки у меня ранее не было. Позднее я решил переделать дизайн и удалил несколько панелей, после чего и началась такая ошибка, однако, удаленные компоненты никак не влияют на этот кусочек кода.

Comment: прям мистика какая то